# Ruby - How to reproduce the pointers/references behavior?

Tags: ruby, pointers, reference, instance

I am currently trying to create an engine for a new application.

Design is quite complex and i realy need a way to create a reference or a pointer or what ever way to remotely modify and access the datas. Datas must be kept in a single place and must not be duplicated.

Is there a way do get an object by reference ?
For example can I get the instance of a class with his object_id ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should demonstrate how to get a reference to an object and de-reference it:

```
   s = "I am a string"                    #=> "I am a string"
   r = ObjectSpace._id2ref(s.object_id)   #=> "I am a string"
   r == s                                 #=> true
```

You may wish to review the documentation for [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html) and [ObjectSpace](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ObjectSpace.html).

Comment: This is looking just great :D I'm testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve. Ruby uses references for all custom objects already.

You may want to look at the `delegate` library.

```
require 'delegate'

obj = "foo"
ptr = SimpleDelegator.new(obj)
ptr.upcase # => "FOO"
other_obj = "bar"
ptr.__setobj__(other_obj)  # make ptr point to another object
```

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for, i will give it a try :) thanks !